# I have problems using Getx and flip_card library

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]I use getx and flip_card to make a card flipping game for children, but I have a problem when I want to handle when a player flips the wrong card, the cards will automatically close, but my code doesn't work properly, I I don't know where I went wrong, hope someone can help.[My Github](https://github.com/YenNN0205/flip_game)

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flip_card/flip_card.dart';
import '../controllers/flip_card_controller.dart';
import 'component/score_memory_game_widget.dart';

class FlipCardMemoryGame extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlipCardMemoryGame({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FlipCardMemoryGame> createState() => _FlipCardMemoryGameState();
}

class _FlipCardMemoryGameState extends State<FlipCardMemoryGame> {
  final controller = Get.put(FlipCardGameController());
  final flipCardController = FlipCardController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.initializeGame();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FlipCardController flipController = FlipCardController();
    double maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFe85d75),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            width: maxWidth,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "MEMORY GAME",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 42, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    scoreWidget(title: "TRIES", value: 0),
                    scoreWidget(title: "SCORE", value: 0),
                  ],
                ),
                Obx(
                  () => GridView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
                      primary: false,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      gridDelegate:
                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisCount: 3,
                              childAspectRatio: 3.5 / 4,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 15,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 15),
                      itemCount: controller.flipCardData.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                        return FlipCard(
                          controller: flipController,
                          onFlip: () {
                            controller.flipCard(index);
                          },
                          flipOnTouch: true,
                          fill: Fill.fillFront,
                          // Fill the back side of the card to make in the same size as the front.
                          direction: FlipDirection.HORIZONTAL,
                          // default
                          side: CardSide.FRONT,
                          // The side to initially display.
                          front: controller.flipCardData[index].isMatched
                              ? Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                      controller.flipCardData[index].img,
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill)
                                  // const Icon(Icons.question_mark,color: Colors.white,size: 42,),
                                  )
                              : Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.orange,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                                  child: const Icon(
                                    Icons.question_mark,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 42,
                                  )),
                          back: controller.flipCardData[index].isMatched
                              ? Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                      controller.flipCardData[index].img,
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill)
                                  // const Icon(Icons.question_mark,color: Colors.white,size: 42,),
                                  )
                              : Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.orange,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                                  child: const Icon(
                                    Icons.question_mark,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 42,
                                  )),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:game/models/flip_card_model.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class FlipCardGameController extends GetxController{

  // final data = DummyData().data;
RxList<FlipCardModel> flipCardData =  DummyData().data.obs;
RxList<FlipCardModel> selectedCard = <FlipCardModel>[].obs;
RxBool isProcessing = false.obs;

void initializeGame(){
  flipCardData.shuffle();

}

void flipCard(int index){
  print("taped");
  if(isProcessing.value || flipCardData[index].isMatched)return;
  if(selectedCard.length<2){
    flipCardData[index].isFlipped = ! flipCardData[index].isFlipped;
    selectedCard.add(flipCardData[index]);
    if(selectedCard.length == 2){
      isProcessing.value =true;
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3),(){
        if(selectedCard.first.key == selectedCard.last.key){
          selectedCard.first.isMatched =true;
          selectedCard.last.isMatched =true;
        }
        selectedCard.clear();
        isProcessing.value =false;
      });
    }
  }
}

}
```

```
class FlipCardModel{
  final String img;
  final int key;
  bool isFlipped;
  bool isMatched;

  FlipCardModel({
    required this.img,
    required this.key,
    required this.isFlipped,
  }) : isMatched = false;
}

class DummyData{
  List<FlipCardModel> data = [
    FlipCardModel(img: "assets/image/flip_card/cat.png", key: 1,isFlipped: false),
    FlipCardModel(img: "assets/image/flip_card/cat.png", key: 1,isFlipped: false),
    FlipCardModel(img: "assets/image/flip_card/elephant.png", key: 2,isFlipped: false),
    FlipCardModel(img: "assets/image/flip_card/elephant.png", key: 2,isFlipped: false),
    FlipCardModel(img: "assets/image/flip_card/mouse.png", key: 3,isFlipped: false),
    FlipCardModel(img: "assets/image/flip_card/mouse.png", key: 3,isFlipped: false),
    FlipCardModel(img: "assets/image/flip_card/stick.png", key: 4,isFlipped: false),
    FlipCardModel(img: "assets/image/flip_card/stick.png", key: 4,isFlipped: false),
    FlipCardModel(img: "assets/image/flip_card/fish.png", key: 5,isFlipped: false),
    FlipCardModel(img: "assets/image/flip_card/fish.png", key: 5,isFlipped: false),
    FlipCardModel(img: "assets/image/flip_card/leopard.png", key: 6,isFlipped: false),
    FlipCardModel(img: "assets/image/flip_card/leopard.png", key: 6,isFlipped: false),
  ];
}
```

I have tried many ways but it always doesn't work, is it because there is a problem with the flip_card library?
Because after flipOnTouch: true. When I click on it, I can no longer flip it. I don't really understand the principles of this library.
I hope everyone can watch and help me. My English is not good so if there are any mistakes, please forgive me. Thank you very much.

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game is nice, basically what you need is to do a selectedCard.refresh(); But I think you can do something different. Here I give you a suggestion in which I change the approach a little.

```
import 'package:flip_card/flip_card.dart';
import 'package:flip_card/flip_card_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../controllers/flip_card_controller.dart';
import 'component/score_memory_game_widget.dart';

class FlipCardMemoryGame extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlipCardMemoryGame({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FlipCardMemoryGame> createState() => _FlipCardMemoryGameState();
}

class _FlipCardMemoryGameState extends State<FlipCardMemoryGame> {
  final controller = Get.put(FlipCardGameController());
  final flipCardController = FlipCardController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.initializeGame();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final RxList par = [].obs;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFe85d75),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            width: maxWidth,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "MEMORY GAME",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 42, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    scoreWidget(title: "TRIES", value: 0),
                    scoreWidget(title: "SCORE", value: 0),
                  ],
                ),
                GridView.builder(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
                    primary: false,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 3,
                            childAspectRatio: 3.5 / 4,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 15,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 15),
                    itemCount: controller.flipCardData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                      final FlipCardController flipController =
                          FlipCardController();

                      return Obx(
                        () => FlipCard(
                            controller: flipController,
                            onFlip: () async {
                              //add to list
                              par.add({
                                controller.flipCardData[index].key:
                                    flipController
                              });
                              par.refresh();

                              if (par.length == 2) {
                                if (par[0].keys.first == par[1].keys.first) {
                                  if (kDebugMode) {
                                    print("match");
                                  }
                                  par.clear();
                                } else {
                                  if (kDebugMode) {
                                    print("not match");
                                  }

                                  await Future.delayed(
                                      const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
                                  par[0].values.first.toggleCard();
                                  par[1].values.first.toggleCard();

                                  par.clear();
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            flipOnTouch: par.length < 2 ? true : false,
                            fill: Fill
                                .fillFront, // Fill the back side of the card to make in the same size as the front.
                            direction: FlipDirection.HORIZONTAL, // default
                            side: CardSide
                                .FRONT, // The side to initially display.
                            front: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.orange,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                                child: const Icon(
                                  Icons.question_mark,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 42,
                                )),
                            back: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                    controller.flipCardData[index].img,
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill)
                                // const Icon(Icons.question_mark,color: Colors.white,size: 42,),
                                )),
                      );
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: (the flipOnTouch: par.length < 2 ? true : false) is for If there are two open, do not allow open other. I also put the flipController inside the itemBuilder so that each  FlipCard has its controller.

Comment: Thank you for your support, everything is ok, however when 2 cards match, the player can still click on it and turn it face down, I solved that problem by creating a
 List<int >listCorrect to store the keys of matching cases, then enter

`flipOnTouch: par.length < 2 ? listCorrect.contains(controller.flipCardData[index].key) ? false : true : false`

I'm not sure if this is the most optimal way.
​

Comment: One problem I don't understand is 
`par.add({controller.flipCardData[index].key : flipController});`
What is its purpose, can you explain to me?

Comment: Yes, 'par' is a list of maps List<Map<int,FlipCardController>>. The map that is added to the list contains one element, the flipController. The goal is to be able to access the flipController of the flipCard being revealed in order to perform a .toggleCard() when needed, such as in the case that they are not the same. the idea is to be able to manage FlipCard through its FlipCardController