# How to use FlipCardController to flip a specific card on a condition?

Tags: flutter

I am creating a memory game with flutter.
For that I am using "flip_card" and riverpod.
So far it is fine. Now I want to flip the cards back if two cards have been flipped.
I tried to implement this, but it is not working. I wonder how to assign which cards should be flipped. I thought using the FlipCardController from "flip_card."

First I am using a BoardsScreen class to build the board.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:memory/data/nini_cards.dart';
import 'package:memory/models/playcard.dart';
import 'package:memory/widgets/playcard_grid_item.dart';
import 'package:memory/providers/cards_provider.dart';

class BoardScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const BoardScreen({super.key});

  void _selectCard(BuildContext context, Playcard playcard) {
    final firstCard = playcard.back;
    print(firstCard);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // final cardsFlipped = ref.watch(cardProvider).length;
    final cardsFlipped = ref.watch(cardProvider);
    print('board: ${cardsFlipped.toString()}');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Pick your cards'),
      ),
      body: GridView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,
        ),
        children: [
          for (final playcard in doubledCards)
            PlaycardGridItem(playcard: playcard)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

From the board this widget is used to display the different cards:

```
# lib/widgets/playcard_grid_item.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:memory/models/playcard.dart';
import 'package:flip_card/flip_card.dart';
import 'package:memory/providers/cards_provider.dart';
import 'package:flip_card/flip_card_controller.dart';

class PlaycardGridItem extends ConsumerWidget {
  PlaycardGridItem({super.key, required this.playcard});
  // late FlipCardController _controller;

  final Playcard playcard;

  final _controller = FlipCardController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // var isFlipped = true;
    final cardsFlipped = ref.watch(cardProvider);
    print('GridItem cardsFlipped: $cardsFlipped');

    if (cardsFlipped.length == 2) {
      print('CardsFlipped == 2');
      _controller.toggleCard();
    }

    return Material(
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        child: FlipCard(
          controller: _controller,
          // onFlip: onSelectCard,

          flipOnTouch: (cardsFlipped.length > 1) ? false : true,

          onFlip: () {
            // isFlipped = ref.read(cardProvider.notifier).flipCard(playcard);
            ref.read(cardProvider.notifier).flipCard(playcard);
            // print('GridItem: ${isFlipped}');
          },
          // flipOnTouch: isFlipped,
          front: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 10,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(playcard.front),
              // child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/sheep.png'),)
            ),
          ),
          back: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 10,
            child: Center(
                // child: Text(playcard.back),
                child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/${playcard.back}'),
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              height: 200,
              width: double.infinity,
            )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Has anybody an idea how to flip the 2 tuned cards back?

Answer (score 0):

A while ago i helped another person with a similar problem, look at the following link, you can even see the repository.

[I have problems using Getx and flip_card library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77426439/i-have-problems-using-getx-and-flip-card-library/77426911#77426911)

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately the repository link is not valid any more.
@yênnguyen Could you please provide the repo?

Comment: oh, Luckily I have a copy, take it, from here https://github.com/franklin83diaz/game-flip_game

Comment: Thank you. I am trying it. As it looks, here Getx is used as state management. I have used riverpod and currently experiencing with provider. What is your experience, which would you recommend?

Comment: Recommending getx would be very controversial lol, many developers are already against using getx, I specifically use it for small projects in which I will not do testing and they will not be scalable. I recommend that you take the logic of the project and do it with riverpod.

Comment: Thank you. I have made a simple example from the flip-card-animation where the coin should be toogled automatically, _controller.toggleCard(), when it has been toogled 3 times. But it does not work. May be you like to take a look at: https://github.com/Genjito/flutter-flip-coin-test and give some advice on it.
I have added this:


class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int value = 0;
  var fpc = FlipCardController();

  void increment() {
    value += 1;
    print('Value is now: $value');

    if (value == 3) {
      fpc.toggleCard();
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}